# How to include github tool into docker container?

Tags: docker

I have build a c# asp.net web api that uses a github tool. It calls it from the code and does all kind of things with the output given by the tool. For development it was quite easy to build, since the tool was on my computer and it could be called from the command line.

The problem that I am facing is now making a docker container of my applicaiton. I have tried 2 different ways of 'downloading' the github tool into the docker container so that it could be used from the code.

**The first way:**

The first way was by using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=DEVELOPMENT

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip wget

# Install dependency-check
RUN mkdir /dependency-check \
    && wget https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/releases/download/v8.3.1/dependency-check-8.3.1-release.zip -O /dependency-check/dependency-check.zip \
    && unzip /dependency-check/dependency-check.zip -d /dependency-check


COPY ["DependencyCheckAPI/DependencyCheckAPI.csproj", "DependencyCheckAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DependencyCheckAPI/DependencyCheckAPI.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/DependencyCheckAPI"
RUN dotnet build "DependencyCheckAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DependencyCheckAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DependencyCheckAPI.dll"]
```

This shows on building that the tool is correctly downloaded, but when trying the command from the terminal of the docker container, the tool does not exist and cannot be used.

**The second way:**

The second way was to actually download the tool into the root folder of my project and copying it into the docker container so that I could use it from there. The problem with that is that all the folders get copied correctly, except for the bin folder where the executable of the github tool is located, which I need. I have no clue why specifically the bin folder gets skipped and can't find docker build errors that are related to it.
The dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=DEVELOPMENT

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["DependencyCheckAPI/DependencyCheckAPI.csproj", "DependencyCheckAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DependencyCheckAPI/DependencyCheckAPI.csproj"
COPY . .

COPY dependency-check-8.3.1-release/ /app/dependency-check-8.3.1-release/

WORKDIR "/src/DependencyCheckAPI"
RUN dotnet build "DependencyCheckAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DependencyCheckAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=build /app/dependency-check-8.3.1-release /app/dependency-check-8.3.1-release

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DependencyCheckAPI.dll"]
```

**My question:**

By now I am beginning to doubt how this can be achieved. How can you download a github command line tool like dependency-check alongside your project so that it can be used in the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to run the tool? Have you put `/dependency-check` in the path? Can you see it with `ls` from the terminal?

Comment: In the first or second method? In the first method, I could not even find the tool and not use it via the terminal. In the second way it skipped downloading the bin folder, so there was no .sh file to run

Comment: @JonSkeet How would you do it if you had to do it for a project? Way 1, way 2 or another way I am not thinking of?

Comment: In the first method. Can you at least see the `/dependency-check` directory in the first method? If you remove the `rm` part, can you see the zip file?

Comment: @JonSkeet nope, when I use docker desktop and use the terminal to go into the container, I cant see the dependency-check folder

Comment: Okay, then I'd *start* by posting a complete Dockerfile which *just* does that, so that it's easy to reproduce. I'd also suggest removing the asp.net tag, as it's completely irrelevant to everything in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the feedback! I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Right, I believe the problem is your use of a multi-stage Dockerfile - you're downloading the tool in the second stage, but never copying it out of that stage.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are talking about the first way right?

Comment: Yes, throughout. (This sort of thing is much easier to discuss when you present a single approach and ask why it's not working.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jon Skeet the problem is known now. He said that that:

> "The problem is your use of a multi-stage Dockerfile - you're
> downloading the tool in the second stage, but never copying it out of
> that stage"

After editing the first way I tried it and added this blow above the `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DependencyCheckAPI.dll"]` line:

```
COPY --from=build /dependency-check/ /app/dependency-check/
```

Now it does download the tool correct and it is visible with the bin folder included. Now I only have to make it work, but the files are there!